# recorrer los elementos padres de un input y determinar si cuentan con una clase

Tags: angular, angular7

Necesito recorrer cada uno de los elementos padres de un input y verificar si alguno de ellos tiene implementada una clase.

```
<div>
   <div [ngClass]="{'myClass':active === true}">
     <ul>
       <li>
         <input #elementChild "[formControl]="formControl">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

de encontrar el elemento padre que contiene la clase (myClass) necesito implementar un método.

He buscado si @ViewChild cuenta con alguna forma de recorrer u obtener los parents Element pero no encuentro nada al respecto.

Comment: Exactamente no explicas lo que quieres conseguir. Pero tienes el método [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) que tu busca el padre(ancestro) mas cercano que coincida con el selector que le pases. Quizá te sirva

Comment: Si estás usando Angular, casi siempre hay una forma de resolver cualquier necesidad sin usar el DOM. ¿Qué es lo que quieres conseguir? ¿Interviene más de un componente?

Comment: @hawks closest buscaría en el padre mas cercano pero necesito buscar en cualquiera de los elementos superiores donde esta anidado el input. De enontrar la clase en un elemento superior pueda deshabilitar el input. La clase la incluyo mediante  una condición en un ngClass pero los niveles de anidacion del input pueden variar.

Comment: pues eso si input es un elemento anidado y algun padre tiene esa clase que buscas pues puedes encontrar el elemento con el closest. No se que quieres decir con "cualquiera de los elementos" si con esto te refieres buscar cualquier elemento que exista en el DOM con esa clase ya no estamos hablando de la anidación del input.

Comment: si tienes acceso a la variable `active` ya sabes que tiene esa clase o no(` [ngClass]="{'myClass':active === true}"`). Solo con comprobar si `active === true` puedes ejecutar el método. Si necesitas ejecutar un método en el componente hijo puedes pasar `active` como `@Input`

Comment: @hawks disculpa no tenia claro el funcionamiento pleno de closest creía que solo aplicaba al mas próximo o cercano elemento padre y no que verificaba cada uno de los elementos padres del input es decir para el código de ejemplo que coloque pensaba que solo buscaba en el `<li>`. Tienes razón sobre la apreciación sobre la variable active pero necesito es determinar esto por la implementacion de la clase y no por la variable active, se que puede sonar extraño

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal como he puesto en los comentarios puedes hacer lo siguiente.

En tu `component.ts`

```
@ViewChild('inputRef') inputRef: ElementRef;

// yo no se cuando necesitas validar lo de la clase
// lo puedes poner el ngOnInit
// o donde tu creas

// puedes hacer la validación así 
parentElemHasMyClass() {
   if (this.inputRef && this.inputRef.nativeElement) {
      return this.inputRef.nativeElement.closest('.myClass');
   }
   return false;
}
```

```html
<div [ngClass]="{'myClass':active === true}">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input #inputRef [formControl]="formControl">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```